# Django: Display model values in table

Tags: python, html, django, url, django-models

I am a newbie to django and need some help. I have a created a vaguely functioning website. I have a model which looks as follows;

```
from django.db import models

class InductiveSensors(models.Model):
   Part_No = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   Manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   Sn = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   AssuredSn = models.CharField(max_length=250)


def __str__(self):
    return InductiveSensors.Manufacturer
```

There are a couple of pages. one which gives me a list of all items in the database

```
{% extends "ESensFind/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
{% for InductiveSensors in object_list %}
<h5>{{ InductiveSensors.Manufacturer}}<a 
href="/Inductive_Search/{{InductiveSensors.id}}"> 
{{InductiveSensors.Part_No}}</a></h5>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

When the {{InductiveSensors.Part_No}} link is clicked it opens up another page. On which I would like to display this database entry in a table with the information of

```
   Part_No = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   Manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   Sn = models.CharField(max_length=250)
   AssuredSn = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

my urls look like:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from Inductive_Search.models import InductiveSensors

urlpatterns = [  
url(r'^$',ListView.as_view(queryset=InductiveSensors.objects.all().order_by
("Manufacturer") #THIS PAGE IS THE LIST OF ALL DATABASE ENTRIES#
[:25],template_name="Inductive_Search/Inductive_Search.html")),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', ListView.as_view(model= InductiveSensors, 
template_name = 'Inductive_Search/SensorInfo.html')) #THIS OPENS UP A NEW 
INDEX PAGE AFTER A PARTICULAR DATABASE ENTRY LINK IS CLICKED#
```

is the 2nd url code correct to work in conjunction with "SensorInfo.html"? In "SensorInfo.html" i have this code, which I would think should display even just the manufacturer information in a header but it displays nothing.

```
{% extends "ESensFind/header.html" %}

{% block content %}
<h5>{{ InductiveSensors.Manufacturer}}</h5>

{% endblock %}
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is get SensorInfo.html to display the values from my model, relating to that particular index in a table on my webpage. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The "right" solution is to write detail view (by deriving from `DetailView`), when in the template you can access the underlying object using `get_object`() or .object.

If you want to implement it quick and dirty, you have to access the `pk` argument and using it get the model instance, and pass it as part of the context data.

I suggest you dig into documentation, the django tutorial is good place to start (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/#writing-your-first-django-app-part-1) or read on class based views here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

Answer (score 0):

So would a solution be something like the following to urls.py?

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from Inductive_Search.models import InductiveSensors

urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', 
ListView.as_view(queryset=InductiveSensors.objects.all().order_by
("Manufacturer") 
[:25],template_name="Inductive_Search/Inductive_Search.html")),
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(model= InductiveSensors, 
template_name = 'Inductive_Search/SensorInfo.html'))
]
```

and in the template

```
{% extends "ESensFind/header.html" %}

{% block content %}

    <h5>{{ get_object() }}</h5>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I have essentially followed this persons tutorials on YouTube: [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W66TcJ7i-Bk.  I have got to video 10 and everything is working, my frustration is at around 7.00min in the video he uses {{post.title}}. In my case this would be {{InductiveSensors.Manufacturer}}, I can't understand why this information isn't being displayed when I load my url.